# OpenCV is preinstalled in google colab but I am unable to add extra modules from opencv contrib. Still getting the same- No such file or directory

Tags: opencv, google-colaboratory

I want to add opencv2/cudaimgproc.hpp module from contrib. I followed the instructions in https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib to build opencv contrib. I also cloned opencv master because the instructions said so even though I have opencv 4 installed in Google colab. I still get the same error-
fatal error: opencv2/cudaimgproc.hpp: No such file or directory  #include 
when I run the cpp code with #include . Please help.